# How to email a parsed JSON using a script

Tags: javascript, html, json, css, email

I have a script that gets and parses a JSON, I want to email the JSON values directly from the script when the page loads. I already have everything set up but do not know the best approach about doing this. I usually use forms to send information but this is a little different.

I am not looking for someone to hold my hand and show me how, I just want to know the different options and I can figure it out myself.

Comment: What have you tried and what specific part of this big problem are you having problem with?

Comment: aside from research, I have not done much because I do not know about this much. I usually use forms to get and send information. It seems that there are api's that could be used from google and yahoo etc but since I never tried doing it this way before so I thought I would ask for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any native javascript functionality for sending emails. I would use a service like https://www.emailjs.com/ or the Gmail javascript API if it was totally necessary to do this from javascript.

Comment: Thank you, emailjs is what did the trick for me. It was easy to setup and use

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automatically send an email using plain javascript from the browser, you can't. You'll have to setup node & use something like nodemailer:

https://nodemailer.com/

If this isn't the case, you can use `window.open` and pass the email data in this way. It will open the default email client on your computer & pre fill an email with the parsed information. Like so:

```
window.open('mailto:your@email.com?subject=your_subj&body='+YOUR_JSON_HERE);
```

Make sure your passing **json** and not a **javascript** object. If you're passing a js object it will return [object object]. If this is the case you'll need to stringify the js object, like so:

```
JSON.stringify(JS_OBJ)
```